# Update input type="time" not working

Tags: javascript, input, time

I'm trying to use onClick to update an input type="time" field with the time listed in a td.  I'm using,

```
document.getElementById("modal-checkin").value = Check_In;
```

I found an example on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_input_time_value.asp but it's not updating the field. Can someone tell me what I'm missing/ doing wrong?

Here's the relevant code I'm using to pass the time variable.
I use php to pull the times from my database then I'm (trying) to use javascript to put the time the user selects into a pop up modal.

```
<?php
$In = $row['CheckIn']->format('g:i');
print '<td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  onClick="TimeAdjustFunction(\'   '.$In.'   \')" >';
?>

<div class="modal-table-Bottom">
    <div>Check In</div><div><input type="time"  id="modal-checkin" /></div>
</div>

<script>
function TimeAdjustFunction(In){
var Check_In = In;
console.log(Check_In);
document.getElementById("modal-checkin").value = Check_In;
}
</script>
```

console.log shows 8:45 (*whatever time I click)

Comment: What do you expect?
It doesn't reload the page, thus the php script doesn't get executed again. So it is always the same time. Do you need to get the time from Php?

Comment: You're blurring the lines between what PHP can do and what Javascript can do. PHP is only run when the page is first loaded. You can request the time as much as you want, it will always be the same value. You should A) Get the time with Javascript, which is live updating, or B) Make an AJAX request to a PHP script which returns the time.

Comment: The times are stored in a database and loaded into the list via php on page. There is a popup modal that starts out blank but needs to get/ fill in the time the user clicks on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem.
input type=time is expecting the time with leading zeros. I was using

->format('g:i')

I changed the 'g' to an 'h' and now it works.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add seconds.

```
var Check_In = In + ':00';
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. you don't need to have the second.